# Build a stable numerical computing environment with Python on Linux

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I am working on my PhD thesis and should finish the results section next week. Since I did an apt-get upgrade, [matplotlib](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matplotlib) does not work anymore:

> ImportError: cannot import name '_tkagg'

I found several solutions. One of them was to install python-tk and rebuild matplotlib from source, but that failed due to some reasons I do not know any more (have to try that again).

Is there a way to build a stable Python, [NumPy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy), [SciPy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SciPy), matplotlib[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matplotlib), [Pandas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandas_%28software%29) environment on Linux ([Debian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian)). Which will never be updated. Or somehow a "stable" numerical computing environment.

EDIT:

What about using `virtualenv` in order to build an independent and stable/working python environment ?

Comment: Really not a programming question. But you should give **anaconda python** a try.

Comment: Thanks for that tip. Just downloaded it.

Answer (score 2):

I used `numpy`/`scipy` under Debian for my thesis too.

If you want stable software, find something that works and don't upgrade it. Otherwise... bugs happen, especially if you're running Debian unstable.

I realize that many of us run `apt-get dist-upgrade` willy-nilly just because we like to get the latest features in every package, but there's no free lunch: if you want the very latest features, you will also get the very latest bugs, incomplete upgrade scripts, etc.

Comment: Not sure why this would have been downvoted as it is obviously correct, if you want a stable environment do NOT use the testing/unstable branch of the distribution, or at least pay attention to what you are doing and what bugs exist.  In this case the bug is known (has been reported a few times) and there are workarounds https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=750630 .